# What is that Dell laptop on Ubuntu home page?

Tags: laptop, dell

With the release of *Natty Narwhal*, the Ubuntu homepage is sporting a new look - *the one with a Dell laptop*. I'm interested to know **what Dell laptop model is that?** It looks really nice but I can't find it on Dell website. I found a similar looking Vostro but not the same exact model. If anyone has any idea what it is, please post a link.  And sorry if questions like this one are not allowed here. This does not seem to be a technical question more of sales. :D

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [**Vostro 3500**](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/vostro-3500/pd).

Too bad, that Dell doesn't offer it as one of [laptops with pre-installed Ubuntu](http://www.dell.com/ubuntu/).

Comment: Nah, I've looked at that model already. It is not the same. The front jacks are at the center for V3300 while the one at the Ubuntu site has it on the right.

Comment: @Marky: right, that's the 15" version from the same line... updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Vartec. Now they look the same or maybe. I looked up http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Dell, sadly the model is not there, like you said. :9  I think the price would've been lower if Windows 7 is not included by default. And no option to not install it?

Comment: @Marky: Theoretically yes. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_refund

Answer (score 0):

That is an Acer Aspire S3 on the Ubuntu home page.